# Get a value from array via a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem in my PHP code. I got an array like this as example ( this array is created dynamic with data from a database).

```
$db_res =array('debiteur_id'=>'1020','user_id'=>'495','b2b_or_b2c'=>'B2C');
```

When I show the values with

```
foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
{
   echo $key.' - '.$value.' , ';
}
```

It is displaying these values what is OK

> debiteur_id - 1020 , user_id - 495 , b2b_or_b2c - B2C

Now I have a function to test if some  data in the array is set or not and to return some values from this $db_res array of $_POST array

```
    function isnull_post($naam)
    {
        if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
            return($db_res[$naam]);
        else
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                return($_POST[$naam]);
            else
                return('');
        }
    }
```

When I use the following code to show my array

```
    foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
    {
        echo $key.' - '.$value.' , ';
        $val = isnull_post($key);
        echo ('isnull : '.$val.' , ');
    }
```

This is my output

> debiteur_id - 1020 , isnull : , user_id - 495 , isnull : , b2b_or_b2c - B2C , isnull :

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$db_res` is not accessible in your function `isnull_post` you need to pass it along with the key.

Comment: or you can use `global $db_res;` as first line in your function `isnull_post`

Comment: What about the `$db_res` value!? which you have written in the function!? Is it global variable!? Just try to print that value in that function so that you came to know if it will return the value or not!? What array it will print let me know.

Comment: Please **do not do** what Amit has suggested

Comment: Hello Phil, Why not doing what Amit suggested, that is the answer that does what I expected

Comment: so is $_POST here also an array ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes in isnull_post() function as your  $db_res array scope is not global. So make it global in the function where you want to use it as a global variable.

```
function isnull_post($naam)
    {   
            global $db_res;

            if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
                return($db_res[$naam]);
            else
            {
                if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                    return($_POST[$naam]);
                else
                    return('');
            }
    }
```

You can also do it by passing the array to the function as :

```
 $db_res =array('debiteur_id'=>'1020','user_id'=>'495','b2b_or_b2c'=>'B2C');

    function isnull_post($naam,$db_res)
        {   
            if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
            return($db_res[$naam]);
            else
            {
                if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                    return($_POST[$naam]);
                else
                    return('');
            }
        }

        foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
        {   
            $val = isnull_post($key,$db_res);
            echo $key.' - '.$val.' , ';
        }
```

if your requirement for using this array is only for this function,then you can pass it to the function but if other functions requires this array then you have to define the array global to that function's body scope.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
$db_res =array('debiteur_id'=>'1020','user_id'=>'495','b2b_or_b2c'=>'B2C');
function isnull_post($naam,$db_res)
{   
    if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
    return($db_res[$naam]);
    else
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
            return($_POST[$naam]);
        else
            return('');
    }
}

foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
{   
    $val = isnull_post($key,$db_res);
    echo $key.' - '.$val.' , ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already is commented, the variable `$db_res` isn't accessible in your function, you either make it a global (which I don't prefer), or you pass it on, like this:

```
<?php
    function isnull_post($naam, $db_res)
    {
        if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
            return($db_res[$naam]);
        else
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                return($_POST[$naam]);
            else
                return('');
        }
    }


    foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
    {
        echo $key.' - '.$value.' , ';
        $val = isnull_post($key, $db_res);
        echo ('isnull : '.$val.' , ');
    }
?>
```

Comment: so is $_POST here also an array ??

Comment: @CodeLover "* ***$_POST:*** *An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method. This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods. "* - [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: yes i got that ..but i see like $_post['name'] .but whats the use of $_post[$var] ??...

Comment: It's bases on the code of the TS, if the function is called like this `isnull_post('user_id')` the function will first check if `$db_res['user_id']` is set, if not it will check if `$_POST['user_id']` is set. What the use of this function is, I don't know... that you ask the TS. Is that what you want to know? Or are you pointing on something else?

Comment: am asking something else ..i just need to know why ($_POST[$naam])) is added here ..

Comment: Because the TS for some reason wants to check if that `$_POST` variable is set....

Comment: ..i have seen assigning like $_POST['something'] but its the first time i have seen assigning like $_POST[$naam] ...is $naam added by the user ??

Comment: so my question will is what will be $naam ..is it the key  of the array $db_res..??

Comment: The use of $_POST[$naam] is used after a submit on the form, I first read my data from the database, my fields have the same name as the ID of my input fields om the form. So when I press submit then the array of $_POST['something'] is created. Now I create a SQL query to save or update data in my database

Comment: You can run with foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) and create dynamic a SQL query

Comment: i didnt get this code ..my question is that i have seen like $var = $_POST['name'] in which name defined in html form..but here the situation is like $_POST[$naam]) ..and $naam is the parameter ..and suppose i have called the function with isnull_post('name',array(something) ..will name be $_POST['name'] ...can i see ur html code ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write any of the way,

```
        $db_res =array('debiteur_id'=>'1020','user_id'=>'495','b2b_or_b2c'=>'B2C');
        function isnull_post($naam)
        {   
            global $db_res;
            if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
            return($db_res[$naam]);
            else
            {
                if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                    return($_POST[$naam]);
                else
                    return('');
            }
        }

        foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
        {   
            $val = isnull_post($key);
            echo $key.' - '.$val.' , ';
        }
```

Or as the following Steps..

```
            $db_res =array('debiteur_id'=>'1020','user_id'=>'495','b2b_or_b2c'=>'B2C');
        function isnull_post($naam,$db_res)
        {   
            if (isset($db_res[$naam]))
            return($db_res[$naam]);
            else
            {
                if (isset($_POST[$naam]))
                    return($_POST[$naam]);
                else
                    return('');
            }
        }

        foreach ($db_res as $key => $value )
        {   
            $val = isnull_post($key,$db_res);
            echo $key.' - '.$val.' , ';
        }
```

But I prefer to use first one.